# Android app for compass calibration to factory settings

Tags: android

The compass in Android phones can be [calibrated manually by twisting the device in a 8-figure pattern](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eloZBMBLQ9o8CC_84rfN-JedVCdzStQhhbs1FImcgOEmUYoeijg-tS4xNh6Kmd234n4=w350). Is there an Android app that is able to change the compass calibration (resetting it to factory settings) by itself, without requiring moving the device?

Comment: Thanks, cleaning up the comments then. Good luck! Basically I'd say it should be as simple as deleting the data from "the compass app", if there were such. If other approaches (not requiring an app; think e.g. of some ADB or Terminal commands) would be acceptable, you could try asking for "How to reset the compass" on Android.SE.